# Pointwise and Uniform converge of $f_n(x) = \frac{nx^2}{1 + nx}, x \in [0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm learning about sequences of functions and need some help with this problem:

> Investigate pointwise and uniform convergence of the sequence of functions
>   $$f_n(x) = \frac{nx^2}{1 + nx}, x \in [0, 1].$$

**My work and thoughts:**

If $x = 0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(0) = \frac{0}{1 + 0} = 0$.

If $x \in (0, 1]$ (i.e. $x \neq 0)$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (undetermined).

Applying *L'Hôpital's rule* we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(nx^2)'}{(1 + nx)'} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2nx}{n} = 2x$.

However, if instead of using *L'Hôpital's rule*, I divide numerator and denominator by $n$ I get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{nx^2}{n}}{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{nx}{n}} = x.$$

---

What am I doing wrong here and what about uniform convergence of $f_n(x)$ on the given interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using L'hospitals rule incorrectly. The limit is in terms of $n$ not $x$ so you'd have to differentiate in terms of $n$ not $x$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{d}{dn}f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}=x$$

Let us try prove uniform convergence using the $\epsilon$ definition. Fix an $\epsilon >0$

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{|nx^2-x(1+nx)|}{|1+nx|}=\frac{x}{1+nx}\leq \frac{1}{1+n} (for \ all  \ x \ in\ the\ interval)$$

Now pick $K(\epsilon)=\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}$. Then for all $n>K(\epsilon)$
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$$

So by definition $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent on the interval.

Comment: Indeed, I get the same result differentiating in terms of $n$. Thank you for this clarification. Since $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f$ where $f = 0$ if $x = 0$ and converges to $x$ otherwise, the sequence of function can't be uniformly convergent on $[0, 1]$ because $f$ is not continuous on this interval. Is this correct?

Comment: Not necessarily as $f(x)=x$ is also equal to $0$ when $x=0$. Thus there is not a discontinuity at $x=0$. I suspect that this function is actually uniformly continuous. Do you know the $\epsilon$ definition of uniform continuity?

Comment: I know the definition but I'm not sure how to apply it. We can also prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$ (that will prove uniform convergence too). We will have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{x}{1 + nx}$ which is increasing on the interval $[0, 1]$. Therefore it takes it's maximum value for $x = 1$. So $\sup|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{1 + n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence, $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on [0, 1]. Does this seems correct to you?

Comment: To be honest I am not aware of that being a sufficient condition for proving uniform continuity. I am not saying that it isn't, just at this time I can't tell you whether you're correct or not. I"ll edit my answer to give you the epsilon method so at least you have something.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and clear explanation, much appreciated!